# page not found - .aspx Webapplication after VS2012 FTP publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a small .aspx webapplication to test my server, wrote a few lines codes in it. I try publish from Visual Studio and it says successfully published but I dont see anything on my website (if I upload an index.html, I see index.html, so there is no domain issue)

I tried publishing files into my desktop and uploaded from Filezilla, got the same error.

Here is the process screenshare of each step.

[image]

Help kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it: :)

I added "**Default.aspx**" and I only have WebForm1.aspx because IIS recognizes only Default.aspx as homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing to an IIS webserver? If yes check if there are all ASP.NET features installed on the server and if the handlers for aspx pages are registered.
It seems like your webserver doesn't know how to deal with ASPX pages.

Comment: If I go to matchracer.net I see your form with a button "IIS works", so I think it may be your browser that has cached something. Try to clear the browser cache

Comment: the problem was Default.aspx (instead I only had WebForm1.aspx) :) I renamed it to Default.aspx and it worked :)